# Sql inner join only with last row in second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables: `leads` and `tracking_leads`.
Table structure is as below,

```
----------------------------            ----------------------
|    leads                 |            |  tracking_leads     |
----------------------------            ----------------------
| id                       |            |  tracking_id        |
| lead_id                  |            |  lead_id            |
| anzahl_tickets           |            |  field_name         |
| bearbeitungs_id_einkauf  |            |  date               |
----------------------------            -----------------------
```

I need sql for join table lead with tracking_leads table but get only LAST match row in table tracking_leads .

Sql example:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tracking_leads.date, "%d.%m.%Y") as trackDate, SUM(l.anzahl_tickets)
 as sumValue FROM leads as l INNER JOIN tracking_leads ON l.lead_id=tracking_leads.lead_id 
 WHERE  bearbeitungs_id_einkauf <> '' AND  tracking_leads.field_name='bearbeitungs_id_einkauf' 
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tracking_leads.date, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

In this part : `INNER JOIN tracking_leads ON l.lead_id=tracking_leads.lead_id` need only last record from tracking_leads  table.

For example, leads data:

`id    lead_id  anzahl_tickets  bearbeitungs_id_einkauf
1     20       2               100`

tracking_leads data:

`tracking_id   lead_id       field_name                    date
 1             20            bearbeitungs_id_einkauf       2019-05-31  13:55
 2             20            bearbeitungs_id_einkauf       2019-05-31  15:00`

In result i need get :

`2019-05-31    2`

But now i get

`2019-05-31    4`

Because there are duplicated of lead_id (need only last record).

How can i solve this  problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference would be to use an inline view to get the max dates.
A correlated subquery would be executed once for each row, while the inline view would only need to be executed once.

This should work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tl.date, "%d.%m.%Y") as trackDate,
       SUM(l.anzahl_tickets) as sumValue
  FROM leads as l 
 INNER JOIN (
         select x.lead_id, max(x.date) date from tracking_leads x where x.field_name = 'bearbeitungs_id_einkauf' group by x.lead_id
       ) tl ON l.lead_id=tl.lead_id 
 WHERE bearbeitungs_id_einkauf <> ''
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tl.date, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Side node: the test for empty value of *bearbeitungs_id_einkauf* in the WHERE clause is database-specific, so watch out for issues there. In Oracle, for example, there is no such thing as an empty string, so you would have to test it for NOT NULL. I'm assuming this is not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't like the date format DD-MM-YYYY, because you cannot sort by it.  Just use YYYY-MM-DD.

Second, you can use a correlated subquery to get the most recent date:

```
SELECT DATE(tl.date) as trackDate, SUM(l.anzahl_tickets) as sumValue
FROM leads l INNER JOIN
     tracking_leads tl
     ON l.lead_id = tl.lead_id
WHERE l.bearbeitungs_id_einkauf <> '' AND
      tl.field_name = 'bearbeitungs_id_einkauf' AND
      tl.date = (SELECT MAX(tl2.date)
                 FROM tracking_leads tl2
                 WHERE tl2.lead_id = tl.lead_id AND
                       tl2.field_name = tl.field_name
                )
GROUP BY DATE(tl.date);
```

Of course, you can leave your original date format if you prefer.  If you do, you can use:

```
ORDER BY MIN(tl.date)
```

so the results are order by the date.

Comment: Yes, i now about date format but my boss need this formt on html page. And thanks, seems it works! You save my day!

Comment: I have problem, if there are several correct records in second table  they are splited, but i need show them together, for example:
https://clip2net.com/s/41XkOkE

Comment: How can i fix it? Thanks

Comment: @OlxOlx1 . . . That cannot happen with this query.  There should be only one row per date.

Comment: But if i have several leads in group , for example 3 leads i need sum anzhal_tix by group for all 3 leads and get only one value, not three